# drrobot_jaguar4x4 package rosmake error

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everybody,

I am trying to rosmake my package and get this configuration error:

```
chencl@chencl-VirtualBox:~/fuerte_workspace/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player$ rosmake
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['drrobot_jaguar4x4_player']        
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['drrobot_jaguar4x4_player']                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/chencl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140403-210405
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['drrobot_jaguar4x4_player'] to:
['drrobot_jaguar4x4_player']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> DrRobotMotionSensorDriver [ make ]                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< DrRobotMotionSensorDriver [PASS] [ 0.25 seconds ]      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> drrobot_jaguar4x4_player [ make ]                      
[ rosmake ] All 32 linesrrobot_jaguar4x4_player: ... [ 1 Active 16/17 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
  [rosbuild] Building package drrobot_jaguar4x4_player
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests drrobot_jaguar4x4_player
  [rospack] Error: package/stack drrobot_jaguar4x4_player depends on non-existent package player
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'drrobot_jaguar4x4_player'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
    Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package drrobot_jaguar4x4_player written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/chencl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140403-210405/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< drrobot_jaguar4x4_player [FAIL] [ 0.32 seconds ]       
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package drrobot_jaguar4x4_player. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 17 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/chencl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140403-210405
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks in advance

Chun-Lin Chen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147991/drrobot_jaguar4x4-package-rosmake-error/) by [CHENCL](https://answers.ros.org/users/14286/chencl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

search for the package "player" in wiki.ros.org and install the package. It is notified in the error message

`Error: package/stack drrobot_jaguar4x4_player depends on non-existent package player`

Just follow the same way if more errors turn up.

Later if other errors turn, the error message gives the place where the error occurs, for example the line number in some file.cpp. Even that might help you in figuring out the error.

While installing take care that you are installing the package for the correct version of ROS.

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CHENCL](https://answers.ros.org/users/14286/chencl/) on 2014-04-03**:
Thank you for your answer.